# Quarkus use oidc verification only on methode with @RoleAllowed

Tags: cors, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

How use oidc verification on methode with RoleAllowed
Exemple my browser use OPTIONS on path to find out which http methode can be use for cors.

How can i do to respond to all options request without verify token on oidc
(keycloak is my oidc)

thank you all ! ! !

Comment: One of the following 2 options should help: 1) disable proactive authentication (meaning authenticate only when, at the point of accessing the JAX-RS resource, it is proved the authentication is needed), https://quarkus.io/guides/security-proactive-authentication, or 2) permit OPTIONS method for a given group of resources, https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference#matching-on-paths-and-methods. Please try one of these options